# iOS Push Notification Error with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

The code was functioning fine couple of days ago. Then went and worked on the ViewControllers didnt go near the Push Notification Code.

Today it is not working.

I reset the head of my git to go back to previous commits (multiple) times when it worked, and deleted the deriveddata folder still no fix.

My push notification code can be found here:

https://github.com/5tr0k3/iOS-Native/blob/master/AppDelegate.swift

The Log can be found here:

https://github.com/5tr0k3/iOS-Native/blob/master/log.log

I will be very grateful if someone can tell me what is wrong or how to go on about troubleshooting or fixing this.

Comment: Try to go to app settings Capabilities tab, check if your push notification setting is turn on.  Seem Xcode 9 disable some Capabilities options and require user turn on it again manually.

Comment: Done that as well, turned it off, turned it back on, deleted entitlement file, added it again. No use :(